# Edited: HTML Anchor tags gone crazy, need some guidelines

Tags: html, css

here is a simple bug i don't know what is going on. the problem is, i have a menu in HTML.the menu actually contains anchor tags but some links are working and others are not even clickable. any help would be appreciated. Thanks a jug

PS:i have same directory for all pages but some are working and other don't.

this is my code for menu.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="menu.php">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="price.php">Price</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

When i go to ABOUT or SERVICES page, i can not go anywhere else because no anchor tag works.

this is my css for menu

```
#menu
{
    background-color:brown;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    //margin-left:auto;
    width:900px;
}

#menu li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;   
    display: inline; 

}

#menu a {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 17px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#menu a:hover{
    color:#BAD1F3;
}
```

Comment: if they are not clickable, maybe there is a issue with your css rules?

Comment: show the css code for your menu.

Comment: try : `<a href="http://www.yourdomain.com/pagename.php">sometext</a>` or `<a href="./pagename.php">sometext</a>`

Comment: Please check your example is verifiable. All the code you have posted works for me.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses. i have same directory and same css applied on all links but i don't know why all links on these 2 pages are not working. it is strange.

Comment: Again, I would strongly recommend providing a verifiable example. The problem you described is not reproducible with the code you have provided. Please see [this page](/help/mcve) that explains how to create a MCVE.

Comment: @Chris see it here
http://www.apnachulha.comli.com/

Comment: @MehranKhan Thanks. I can see what the problem is and will type up an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the headings on your "Services" and "About Us" page have a padding that overlaps the links. Remove `position: relative;` from the headings and you will find the links are clickable again.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration. i didn't notice that. i'm gonna check that.

Comment: love you for that man. you solved my whole problem. one thing more that i would like you to please explain what was actually the problem with position relative ? what that relative position does ? when and where should we use it ?  what are alternatives for that ?

Comment: @MehranKhan Okay, normally elements are not allowed to overlap. Positioned elements are an exception. When you give an element a position it is allowed to overlap other elements and so when you click on the links you are actually clicking on the padding of the heading rather than on the link.

Answer (score 0):

Menu is floated and overlapped by below element. Add `overflow: hidden;` to `#container` and it will clear the float.